# Mark strings as non-nullable in ASP.NET Core 3.0 Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swashbuckle, c#-8.0

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3 and Swashbuckle with mostly default configuration and I have a DTO parameter with a string on it that I want to be non-nullable. How can I achieve this? Note, Required and nullability are separate concerns in Swagger.

It's also using C#8 and the non-nullable stuff, so the compiler should be annotating the property as non-nullable already. It's understandable that Swashbuckle hasn't been updated to take that into account (and maybe can't) but I would like to be able to override the generated metadata somehow.

```
class MyDto {
    [Required]
    // I want this to show as non-nullable in the swagger documentation (and ideally also be non-nullable in the binding)
    public string TestProp { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] MyDto requestModel) {
}
```

I have tried making it Required. I also tried adding the Newtonsoft annotations, but none of these seemed to do it.

Relevant bit of Swagger doc that is generated:

```
    "MyDto": {
      "required": [
        "testProp"
      ],
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "testProp": {
          "type": "string",
          "nullable": true
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
     }
```

Note that having a string parameter directly as a parameter doesn't generate the nullable attribute. E.g.

```
[HttpPost("testPost")]
public void Post([FromBody] [Required] string testProp) {
}
```

will generate

```
"/api/test/testPost": {
  "post": {
    "tags": [
      "Test"
    ],
    "requestBody": {
      "content": {
        "application/json": {
          "schema": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "text/json": {
          "schema": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "application/*+json": {
          "schema": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "required": true
    },
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Success"
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Swagger is probably not (yet) looking for the `NullableContextAttribute`.

Comment: [This Swashbuckle issue](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1218) shows that currently optional strings *don't* have the `nullable:true` attribute and end up *non*-nullable. The fix will be released in v5 which is still an RC. Which version did you use? And what does the Swagger document look like? Does it actually include `nullable:true` for `TestProp`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using v5-rc4. It does include nullable:true for strings (which is what I don't want as I'm trying to specify that null isn't valid for this particular string)

Comment: @Quails4Eva post the document in the question itself. It looks like the problem was caused by the fix to the linked issue. Even if you simply commented on that issue, the maintainer would want to see the generated `swagger.json`. It would also make it easier for people to understand what you ask

Comment: Have you tried using `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.DisallowNull)]` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have tried the JsonProperty attribute, but I think it doesn't work because the project is using the new Json serialiser rather than Json.Net (I'm not 100% sure that's the reason). I've added the generated docs to the question

Comment: @Quails4Eva you didn't add the results of  using `JsonProperty`. Imagine *you* were posting a new issue - the maintainer doesn't have the time to create a test project. You need to show what the actual problem is and how to reproduce it.  In any case SwashBuckle *does* use the Json.NET attributes even if the rest of the project doesn't. Check [this test class](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/test/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.Test/Fixtures/Types/JsonPropertyAnnotatedType.cs). Which btw explicitly tests for a string with `DisallowNull`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry, it is now working with that attribute. I'm sure I tried it, but maybe I didn't refresh the page correctly or something, that's my bad. Adding the attribute you suggested to TestProp solves the issue. If you want to add that as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Until v4.01 `nullable:true` was emitted for optional strings. This broke in the first 5.0 RC versions and `nullable:true` wasn't emitted at all for optional strings. That, obviously, is wrong.

[Starting with 5.0 RC3](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1218) optional strings are nullable once again.

To specify that an optional string is *not* nullable, you need to add `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.DisallowNull)]` to the property. Copying from [one of Swashbuckle's unit tests](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/test/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.Test/Fixtures/Types/JsonPropertyAnnotatedType.cs), this :

```
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.DisallowNull)]
    public string StringWithRequiredDisallowNull { get; set; }
```

Should [set the property's Nullable flag](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/test/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.Test/SchemaGen/SchemaGeneratorTests.cs#L522) :

```
Assert.False(schema.Properties["StringWithRequiredDisallowNull"].Nullable);
```

And emit `nullable:true`.

Comment: Just check in the latest swashbuckle version 5.6.3,  jsonProperty is not working while RequiredAtrribute works fine

Comment: I can confirm: this solution no longer works.

Comment: I can confirm: this solution works again. In 6.5.0.

Answer (score 26):

You can now use [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) to mark strings as optional or required:

- Enable nullable reference types for your project/solution
- Mark strings in Dtos as nullable:

  ```cs
  public class ExampleDto
  {
     [StringLength(64, MinimumLength = 4)]
     public string RequiredString { get; set; }

     [StringLength(200)]
     public string? OptionalString { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Enable Swagger support in your `Startup.cs`

  ```cs
  services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
  {
      options.SupportNonNullableReferenceTypes();
  });
  ```

This leads to:

```json
{
  "Example": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "requiredString": {
        "maxLength": 64,
        "minLength": 4,
        "type": "string"
      },
      "optionalString": {
        "maxLength": 200,
        "minLength": 0,
        "type": "string",
        "nullable": true
      }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this code fixed my problem. ```options.SupportNonNullableReferenceTypes();```

Comment: that doesn't work for me using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.3.0

Comment: Using .NET 7 with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.5.0, I added this line inside the `AddSwaggerGen` lambda above, where you say to `Enable Swagger support in your Startup.cs`: `options.SchemaGeneratorOptions.SupportNonNullableReferenceTypes = true;` This is with me using only the `Nullable` option enabled on the project + declaring the model property as a `string` (so non-nullable).

Answer (score 3):

In 2023 with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.5.0 which is outputting OpenApi 3.0 - you just need to add the `[Required]` attribute to your response DTO (which is what OP was already doing).