# How can I annotate optional string as not nullable

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle, .net-5

I have a DTO that contains several `string` properties.

None of them are `string?` but swagger somehow descript them as nullable: true.

This is a DTO for serialization so I do not want to annotate them with `[Require]`

Can I annotate them as not nullable without annotating them as Require?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mark strings as non-nullable in ASP.NET Core 3.0 Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58299772/113116)

Comment: @Helen I dunno, They use Newtonsoft.Json but I'm using System.Text.Json and my config and annotation are already based on it.