# How to set not nullable Swagger response property in example schema

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm trying to set some properties here as not null in the swagger response example schema, but i just can do it setting the properties as [Required] on the view model example. I know it's not the correct approach, any ideas?

[image]

Obs. I tryed to use [JsonProperty(Required = Required.DisallowNull)], but it had no effect.

Comment: What library do you use - Swashbuckle, Swagger-Net, NSwag, something else?

Comment: I'm using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.4.0

Comment: Does this answer help? -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58306726/113116

Comment: This solution no longer works, I already tried it. I'll let it as [Required], so the fields cant be nullable. Thanks trying.

Answer (score 0):

Just set this in your AddSwaggerGen

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SupportNonNullableReferenceTypes();
});
```